# How to query JSONB column in Specification

Tags: postgresql, jpa

convert below postgres query to specification query.

```
SELECT *
FROM service_table
WHERE services->>'cancel' IS NOT NULL OR services->>'slot' IS NOT NULL;



public Specification<ServiceTable> hasServices(List<String> servicesList) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String service : servicesList) {
            Predicate services = cb.isNotNull(root.get("services").get(service));
            predicates.add(services);
        }
        return cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```